# Create database in mongoDB using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I am on mongoDB 3 and php version 5.6. I want to create a database for adding data in it. I am trying in this way.

```
<?php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

   // connect to mongodb

   $db = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");

   echo "Connected";

   // select a database
   $data = $db->selectDatabase("admin");

   echo "Done ";
?>
```

This code is running well but not making any database in the `MongoDB`. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you have installed Mongodb driver for PHP and you are not receiving any exception while executing your code.

**After the db connection is established you need to save something in collection so that the db comes to existence.  This is missing in your code.**

Try below code

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->admin;
   echo "Database admin selected";

   $collection = $db->createCollection("mycol");
   echo "Collection created succsessfully";
?>
```